# What are Clojure's AOT limitations?

Tags: clojure, clojure-java-interop

It looks like exposing clojure library api to Java code requires the use of AOT compilation (at least when the exposed api is OO). If I'm wrong about that, I am happy to be revised. In the past, there have been multiple issues with AOT, thusly relying on it may have seemed a bit reckless or unstable.

What is the current state in that?
Is it a safe practice?

Would you use that as a means to expose an OO api to java applications?

Answer (score 3):

You can use AOT to produce bytecode that will pass muster as a Java library. But it's not terribly pleasant, for you or for the Java programmers, who will rightfully ask: Where is the JavaDoc? Why are you using Object instead of generics? And other similarly awkward questions.

Instead, my preferred approach is to not make the Clojure code Java-friendly at all. Expose it as ordinary Clojure vars, and that's it. Then, write some Java code yourself, in the same library, that consumes the Clojure-based API and repackages it in terms of whatever Java constructs you want.

For one example, see my [thrift-gen](https://github.com/amalloy/thrift-gen) library. Using it from Clojure, you get a function that takes a map as input and produces a sequence; using it from Java, you get a builder pattern for configuration instead of the map, and you get a `List<? extends T>` as output. No JavaDoc, because I felt the usage documentation in the readme was sufficient, but if I were serious about using this there is a real .java source file to easily add JavaDoc to.